# solving arithmetical problems - Math.Sqrt does not produce x^2

Tags: c#

[image]

The way I tried to solve the problem is:

```
double nmr1, result;
nmr1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
result = 1 + nmr1 + Math.Sqrt(nmr1) / 2;
label1.Text = result.ToString();
```

Is this a correct answer? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "*Is this a correct answer*" why don't you test it with some sample values?

Comment: You could answer this very easily by plugging in a few values and comparing the result to what your calculator tells you.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for function Math.Sqrt()

Comment: OMG! Y just realized what square LOL seems I was referring to another solution. Sorry ....

Comment: "What I'm doing wrong" - you are mixing input parsing, computation and printing together. For this question there is no need to show all string manipulations - see Nicholas Carey (+1) answer for how sample should have looked like.

Comment: Side note: I've removed all unrelated text/thank you notes. I've also changed title (but now may look bad sorry about that). Please try to make title useful AND not so obvious at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Math.Sqrt(x)` is the square root of x

You want `Math.Pow(x, 2)` to get x squared

Comment: <facepalm/> I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: You're right, of course, but I don't understand why the other answerers feel the need to restate your point.

Comment: @user2648071 If this answered your question, please let Matthew know by checking the Answer mark underneath the Vote buttons.

Answer (score 3):

[`Math.Sqrt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is for the square-root, not squared. Use [`Math.Pow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also use brackets to ensure the [correct calculations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) are made whilst making them more clear:

```
nmr1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
label1.Text = 1 + nmr1 + (Math.Pow(nmr1, 2)/2);
```

Comment: I think based on [order of operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) that by adding your parens here give the only correct answer. (+1)

Comment: -1 Math.Pow() takes two arguments, not one.

Answer (score 3):

ummmm...

```
double f( double x )
{
  double y = 1 + x + (x*x)/2.0 ;
  return y ;
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you have too many lines :P `return 1 + x + (x*x)/2.0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
double nmr1, result;
nmr1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
result = 1 + nmr1 + (nmr1 * nmr1 ) / 2;
label1.Text = result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double nmr1, result;
nmr1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
result = 1 + nmr1 + Math.Pow(nmr1, 2) / 2;
label1.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: How is this any different than Matthew's answer above?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a square root instead of doing a power of two in your calculation. Update this line as follows:
result = 1 + nmr1 + Math.Pow(nmr1, 2) / 2;

Alternatively you can also do this:
result = 1 + nmr1 + (nmr1 * nmr1) / 2;